# Unable to move the file content using Microsoft Flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

When an item uploaded to SharePoint library, the file needs to be posted in Yammer. If a text file is added the file content it is getting posted but when I add the video file, Flow is getting failed.

[Flow Error Message - Not a JSON format]

Any workaround or resolution available.